# Group and order

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to have som help to list mail correct.
Now mail list correct by date/time but wrong lettertext showing.

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  userid, 
  sendid, 
  left(mess,35), 
  max(xdatum) AS maxtid, 
  status, 
  bild, 
  sendname, 
  sendinfo 
FROM mailbox 
WHERE userid='" &Session("userid")& "' 
GROUP BY sendid 
ORDER BY maxtid desc
```

Solution:

> Last text msg.. from Lisa33, 09:33
>
> Last text msg.. from AAAdam, 08:22

and so on..

Bonus if i can get totmail in eacth Group..like:

> Last text msg..(4) from Lisa33, 09:33
>
> Last text msg..(1) from AAAdam, 08:22

Comment: I don't understand what you want, you should be more clear.

Comment: The values for fields that are not group by fields and not aggregate fields will come from an undefined column

Comment: In my sql code alla mail showes but in wrong order.
Its not newest mail that shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using a subselect to get the max xdatum, then joining that against your main table to get the other columns

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  userid, 
  sendid, 
  left(mess,35), 
  Sub1.maxtid, 
  status, 
  bild, 
  sendname, 
  sendinfo 
FROM mailbox 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT sendid, max(xdatum) AS maxtid
    FROM mailbox 
    WHERE userid='" &Session("userid")& "' 
    GROUP BY sendid 
) Sub1
ON mailbox.sendid = Sub1.sendid
AND mailbox.xdatum = Sub1.maxtid
WHERE userid='" &Session("userid")& "' 
ORDER BY maxtid desc
```

Comment: Thanks! its works.
Can it be optimized? 
Its take 8-9 seconds to run this question.
Where are 200.000-250.000 letters in mailbox..

Comment: Would likely depend on the indexes you have, and which ones MySQL has chosen to use. Is there an index on both sendid and xdatum (ie, one index covering both columns)?

Comment: it looks like its only column "id" there have index..
is it safe to set index column "sendid" and "xdatum"?

Comment: Should be safe. Without an index MySQL will have to check every row when doing the join.

Comment: I make them indexed but it gets only 2-3 seconds faster, so i change your code to order by id insted of xdatum, now its fast again.